# How can I change a specific page number to bold?

Tags: formatting, page-numbering

As an ester egg I would like to change the formatting of only one page number and leave all other as they are.

I am using the `article` document class with page number on the bottom of the page in the middle, so nothing fancy:)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is quite unspecific. Which packages are you using? You're not using something `fancy`, but perhaps `fancyhdr` might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `fancyhdr` approach with a `\ifnum` conditional. The specific page number can be set with `\myfancypagenumber`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\def\myfancypagenumber{3}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\ifnum\value{page} = \myfancypagenumber\huge\bfseries \textcolor{blue}{\thepage}\else\thepage\fi}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Another approach with `\getpagerefnumber` which acts only a specific page label, i.e. just place a page label and this will be used for the relevant conditional with `\getpagerefnumber`. (`\pageref` does not work here, since it's not expandable and so  `\ifnum...` fails to compile)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\ifnum\numexpr\value{page} = \getpagerefnumber{mypagelabel}\huge\bfseries \textcolor{blue}{\thepage}\else\thepage\fi}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\blindtext[12]

\hfill\textbf{Here some text}\hfill
\label{mypagelabel}

\blindtext[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to hard code the page number into the document with `def\myfancypagenumber...`unless that is what you really want to do, (for example make page 42 look 'special', independent of the contents of that page). You can define a new page style, then apply it to the relevant page using `\thispagestyle{...}`

Comment: @alephzero: Do you have seen my `update` at all? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I did it using fancyhdr as suggested by Christian.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\cfoot{\ifnum\value{page}=22
 \textbf{\thepage} 
 \else 
 \thepage 
 \fi}
```

To remove the header fanncyhdr adds.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
```

Comment: It's better so provide full compilable examples instead of fragments